# Gremlin - how to assign a list of values to a new property, for multiple vertices

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

Say I have a list of three vertices with IDs `123`, `456`, and `789`.

```
g.V([123,456, 789])
```

How can I add a new property called say `testproperty`, for which I have a list of values, `['a', 'b', 'c']`, which I want to add at the same time?

The pseudo gremlin code - for illustration - and which *doesn't* work is:

```
g.V([123,456, 789]).property('testproperty', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

To be clear, I want a mapping between the two lists, so `g.V(123).property('testproperty', 'a')`, `g.V(123).property('testproperty', 'b')` etc.

So,  `g.V([123,456,789]).valueMap()` should return:

```
==>{testproperty=[a]}
==>{testproperty=[b]}
==>{testproperty=[c]}
```

Comment: that Gremlin looks right to me if you're trying to add "testproperty" with the specified value to each of those three vertices. can you elaborate on what doesn't work?

Comment: Sure thing. It raises the Exception: `Property value [[a, b, c]] is of type class java.util.ArrayList is not supported`

Comment: Hi Stephen, I think I may have miscommunicated my end goal originally, and have made it more clear in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
gremlin> data = [1:'a',2:'b',3:'c']
==>1=a
==>2=b
==>3=c
gremlin> g.inject(data).as('d').
......1>   V(data.keySet()).as('v').
......2>   property('testproperty', select('d').select(select('v').by(T.id)))
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
gremlin> g.V(data.keySet()).valueMap(true)
==>[id:1,label:person,testproperty:[a],name:[marko],age:[29]]
==>[id:2,label:person,testproperty:[b],name:[vadas],age:[27]]
==>[id:3,label:software,testproperty:[c],name:[lop],lang:[java]]
```